# Track recieved emails by script

Tags: netsuite

I have a user-event script which changes case record status to 'Waiting for information' when a new mail is sent from case record.
But when anybody replies to that mail, I want the script to change the status again to 'Received'. The user may reply from gmail or outlook.

How to track received mail from outside of netsuite.

```
var loadCase = record.load({
            type: nRecType,
            id: recordid
        })
        if(context.type == context.UserEventType.CREATE || context.UserEventType.EDIT)
        {
                var messagenew = objRecord.getValue('messagenew');
                if(messagenew == true)
                {
                    var question = objRecord.getValue('incomingmessage');
                    log.debug('N','question : '+question);
                    if(question == '' || question == null)
                    {}
                    else
                    {
                        loadCase.setValue({
                            fieldId: 'status',
                            value: 8 //waiting for info
                        })
                    }
                }                                                  
                loadCase.save();                                                
        }
}return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In NS when the customer replies to the email that is sent from a case, NS will re-open the case with status: Re-Opened [open stage]. You need just to set the 'waiting for info' status a  stage. You can even rename the 'Re-Opened' to 'Received'. for "track received mail from outside" a script may be required. It depends on how you want to track them.